# How can I find the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I find the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I tried with $\det(A - aI) = (\cos\phi - a)^2 + \sin^2 \phi = 0$

and I got somehow to $2\cos\phi = a$, and I believe that the eigenvalues have to be $\pm 1$ because it is a private case of rotation matrix (which its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$).

Help is highly appreciated.

and yes, I looked in wiki and other places, I didn't see a solution, to it, just some general explanations and answers, but I want to understand how to solve the equations I wrote above $\det(A-aI)=...$

Comment: If you showed us how you “somehow” got to $2\cos\phi=a$, then we could tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(\cos\phi-a)^2 \geq 0$ and $\sin^2\phi\geq 0$. Therefore the equation $(\cos\phi-a)^2+\sin^2\phi=0$ holds if and only if $\cos\phi=a$ and $\sin\phi=0$. In particular, $\phi$ must be an integer multiple of $\pi$, and in that case the eigenvalue of $A$ will be $\cos\phi$ (which will be $1$ or $-1$ depending on the value of $\phi$). Otherwise, there are no real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get $a=2\cos \phi$? Try computing the determinant again, carefully, and then solving for all possible $a$.

You are right that since $1 = \det I = \det(A^TA) = (\det A)^2$, and since $A$ is real, the product of the eigenvalues must be 1 or -1. But this does not mean that the eigenvalues themselves must be 1 or -1...

Answer (score 1):

Actually the two eigenvalues of your rotation matrix are complex (and not real), and more specifically they are $e^{i\phi}$ and $e^{-i\phi}$. Try to compute again (and carefully) the characteristic polynomial to find this result.

Answer (score 1):

Your characteristic polynomial should be of the form $w^2-2\cos\theta \; w + 1$. Solve it to get your eigenvalues, $w$.